# Out of memory when serving a very big binary file over HTTP

Tags: perl, file, http, out-of-memory, cgi

The code below is the original code of a Perl CGI script we are using. Even for very big files it seems to be working, but not for really huge files.

The current code is :

```
$files_location = $c->{target_dir}.'/'.$ID;
open(DLFILE, "<$files_location") || Error('open', 'file');
@fileholder = <DLFILE>;
close (DLFILE) || Error ('close', 'file');

print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$name\n\n";
print @fileholder;
binmode $DLFILE;
```

If I understand the code correctly, it is loading the whole file in memory before "printing" it. Of course I suppose it would be a lot better to load and display it by chunks ? But after having read many forums and tutorials I am still not sure how to do it best, with standard Perl libraries...

Last question, why is "binmode" specified at the end ?

Thanks a lot for any hint or advice,

Comment: This question is closely related to [Why is my image download CGI script written in Perl not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10563275/100754) in that the code in both seem to have been copied from the same crappy tutorial site. See also my blog post [A file download CGI script in Perl](https://www.nu42.com/2012/05/file-download-cgi-script-in-perl.html) which I wrote in response to that question. The two questions are not exact duplicates because they are failing for different reasons.

Comment: **"why is "binmode" specified at the end?"** ... Because someone who did not know what they were doing copied code from a tutorial written by someone else who did not know what they were doing either. In fact, since the actual file handle is `DLFILE`, `binmode`ing `$DLFILE` is not going to do anything anyway, no matter where it's placed. Its only purpose in life is to indicate that the incompetent person who wrote the script did not `use strict`.

Comment: This *stupid* 14 year old script: `https://www.sitepoint.com/file-download-script-perl/`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. By the way, I don't understand why my question is marked "-1" ? In what way is it "unclear" or "not useful" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what `binmode $DLFILE` is for. `$DLFILE` is nothing to do with the file handle `DLFILE`, and it's a bit late to set the binmode of the file now that it has been read to the end. It's probably just a mistake

You can use this instead. It uses modern Perl best practices and reads and sends the file in 8K chunks

The file name seems to be made from `$ID` so I'm not sure that `$name` would be correct, but I can't tell

Make sure to keep the braces, as the block makes Perl restore the old value of `$/` and close the open file handle

```
my $files_location = "$c->{target_dir}/$ID";

{
    print "Content-Type: application/x-download\n";
    print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name\n\n";

    open my $fh, '<:raw', $files_location or Error('open', "file $files_location");
    local $/ = \( 8 * 1024 );

    print while <$fh>;
}
```

Comment: While the answer is true, anyone who looks for such solution here (e.g. beginners)  *will not* understand what exactly does the `local $/ = \( 8 * 1024 );` (especially the `\(` part). Some short explanation would be nice. (just IMHO).

Comment: Dear Borodin, thanks a lot for your answer. I made it a little different but I think it is the same finally ? I did : while (read($fh, my $buf, 64*1024)) { print $buf; }

Comment: P. S. Another improvement for anyone reading this :
my $filesize = -s $files_location; print "Content-Length: $filesize\n";

Comment: @Borodin: OK finally I used your method, which is more compact indeed ;-)

Comment: @DenisBUCHER: You can use `read` if you wish, but that does exactly the same as my own code (except that it uses 64K instead of 8K) using a lot more characters.

Comment: @DenisBUCHER: Fine. You can change the 8K to 64K if you wish, by using `\(64 * 1024)` but the size of the buffer is arbitrary and will make little difference.

Answer (score 3):

You're pulling the entire file at once into memory. Best to loop over the file line-by-line, which eliminates this problem.

Note also that I've modified the code to use the proper 3-arg [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), and to use a lexical file handle instead of a global bareword one.

```
open my $fh, '<', $files_location or die $!;

print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$name\n\n";

while (my $line = <$fh>){
    print $line;
}
```

The `binmode` call appears to be useless in the context of what you've shown here, as `$DLFILE` doesn't appear to be a valid, in-use variable (add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script...)

Comment: 1. Binary files don't have lines. Best to set `$/` to `\(64*1024)` or something. 2. The solution to the misuse of `binmode` is to use it properly, not eliminate it. Either add `binmode($fh);`, or use `<:raw` instead of `<`.