# Why does perl execute a command take longer than running the command alone?

Tags: apache, perl

When I run the command

```
montage -background black -geometry +0+0 -mode Unframe -tile ${num_digits}x1 $filelist gif:- > ~/temp/count.gif
```

It takes 0.1 seconds to execute (I used `time montage...`).

When I put that command in my perl cgi script

```
print LOG "starting montage\n";
open(GRFX,
    "montage -background black -geometry +0+0 -mode Unframe -tile ${num_digits}x1 $filelist gif:- |"
);
print LOG "finish montage\n";
print <GRFX>;
print LOG "finish output\n";
close(GRFX);
```

The time between "finish montage" and "finish output" is 6 seconds!!

If I run the cgi script from the command line it takes 0.1 seconds. But from within Apache it takes the 6 seconds, even when accessed with a browser on the same computer as Apache (so it is not the Internet slowing things down, also, all other pages load fast regardless of whether the browser is on the same computer).

The resulting gif file generated by montage is 1.7k.

Any ideas why this is so slow when run within Apache?

The only header output is `print "Content-type: image/gif\n\n";`

Comment: Would the down voter please explain the down vote? Seems like a good question to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `print <GRFX>;` to print the output, reading all the lines of output from the piped shell command.

**LINES** is the operative word here. Presumably, the trailing sequence of bytes does not end in a newline, and therefore Perl is waiting around for it. Eventually, it times out.

You can set `local $/ = 4096` to read 4096 byte chunks at a time. Then, output using `print while <GRFX>`.

It would be good form to also [`binmode`](https://perldoc.perl.org/) both `GRFX` and `STDOUT` so you don't get bit by [problems like this](https://www.nu42.com/2014/12/when-bits-dont-stick.html). See also my [blog post](https://www.nu42.com/2012/05/file-download-cgi-script-in-perl.html) on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10563275/100754).

I would be tempted to re-write your code like this (untested):

```
sub output_image {
    my $num_digits = shift;
    my $filelist = shift;

    print LOG "starting montage\n";

    my @cmd = (
        montage => qw(
        -background black
        -geometry +0+0
        -mode Unframe
        -tile),
        "${num_digits}x1",
        split(/ /,$filelist),
        'gif:-'
    );

    open my $GRFX, '-|', @cmd
        or die "Failed to open pipe: $!";

    {
        local $/ = 4096;
        binmode $GRFX;
        binmode STDOUT;
        print while <$GRFX>;
    }

    close $GRFX
        or die "Failed to close pipe: $!";

    print LOG "finish montage\n";
}
```

Comment: I super appreciate your answer! And it has a lot of points that I think are pertinent, but in the end, the code still takes 6 seconds. I pasted your code as is into my counter, called the subroutine in place of my code to create the montage, fixed the one line that didn't pass the image args correctly, and timed at 6 seconds.

Comment: You are welcome. When I get a chance, I'll try to replicate what you are seeing on Linux, and update my answer if I figure out anything.